# Installing Lucene.net CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, lucene.net

I'm trying to install Lucene.net CLI

When I run the command dotnet tool install lucene-cli -g --version [EnvVar:LuceneNetVersion]  I get an error: Specified version '[EnvVar:LuceneNetVersion]' is not a valid NuGet version range.

When I run the command dotnet --list-runtimes, I find that I have Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.11  [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] while the prequisite is .NET Core 3.1.0 Runtime.
I suppose that it's compatible, but I'm not sure.

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: This sounds like a bug.  Can you add the issue on github here: https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/issues Once resolved we can post the solution back here as an answer for the SO community.

Comment: Please also list the version of Lucene.net you are using.

Comment: How can I find which version of Lucene.net cli I am using?

Comment: The problem that I am having is that the one-time install of the lucene-cli tool is throwing an error: Specified version '[EnvVar:LuceneNetVersion]' is not a valid NuGet version range
So I don't have Lucene.net cli installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a documentation build issue.

`[EnvVar:LuceneNetVersion]` is a token that should have been replaced during the docs build.

Please use a real version number here instead like 4.8.0-beta00013

I'll update this issue as a docs issue https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/issues/416